# Are we thinking too much about how a user will interpret a photograph?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, accessibility

Here's something interesting that a friend mentioned while taking a look at a few websites I had mentioned.

It's commonplace nowadays (with accessibility as rife as ever) to place a darkened overlay over the image before text goes on top, so the text is easier to read. It does make sense. You can't read small(ish) text over the top of an image with the same colours in it, it becomes difficult on the eye.

This, however, is not an accurate representation of the photograph. It is true. It's dark, looks depressing and oppressive, whatever word you want. Now, in some instances, a white car for example (close up) could very well have black text on it without such a need for a protective layer, but for most instances, you will need something to help the user read the text.

We will get to my point ;-) Are we just thinking this too much here? Will, a user look at a series of hero images for example or panel images on a website and think, "Woah, these images are dark, I'm depressed, not like the ones you see in art galleries even though we don't go to art galleries". "They are not as bright as the ones that my grandmother showed me from her photo album she took with her disposable camera".

Do you see my point? We need to do 'something', so IF we are to have text on an image (sure we could just put the text below the image) is it perfectly reasonable to darken it so we do not fail accessibility checks?

Comment: It depends on the context, purpose, user, goal, the image itself etc. There is no good answer possible.

Comment: @jazZRo I’m afraid I am not sure I agree. Does putting a black overlay on an image to make the text readable make people think that this site images make me feel low, depressed or even greater turned off?

Comment: Apparently this should be closed for being top opinion based? Like 70% of the other questions on here.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a subjective question, as long as it can be answered with solid arguments that actually answers the question. Read more [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) if you want to know how to improve your question.

Comment: @jazZRo See this is where i’m confused. This whole place is about UX. Someone’s experience, no? How can this not be backed up by valid experiences seeing as this kind of thing happens again and again in the internet. Sure, as below, let’s ask a load of photography people who know probably little about the web, how will that help?

Answer (score 2):

I'll sidestep the question of "is it bad to darken the image," as perhaps the folks at [Photography.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) would be better suited to provide advice there.

However, it doesn't have to be an all-or-nothing method of darkening. You can explore applying a large shadow or darkened box behind only the text, leaving much of the image unchanged.

This may be sufficient to achieve both goals: ensure the text is legible, and leave (most of) the image unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

Typically superimposed text is successful in two scenarios:

- The background image is interesting (serves as a teaser) and the text is driving the user to click and read the story, which has a less-obscured version of the image in it, or
- The background image is less interesting, just decoration, and stays subordinated to more interesting written content on top of it.

It would not be good UX to put a great image under shadows and text and not let the user explore it elsewhere. Doing this with meh images? Probably okay.